# The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: html, banner

The issue is that I can't get this banner to post into my blog, and the error message is what's in the subject. I am trying to update a template with this.  I don't see any missing ; but i've made sillier mistakes today so who knows.

```
<div> id="RightFloatAds;" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px; solid; black;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&id=1"><img src="banner1news.png" width="160" height="725" alt=""><div/>
```

Comment: My original code was '''<div id="RightFloatAds" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&id=1"><img src="banner1news.png" width="160" height="725" alt=""><a/></div>'''

Comment: Replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: I think that is it, thanks

Comment: Now the error is "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4655; columnNumber: 291; The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>".   '''<div id="RightFloatAds" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1"><img src="banner1news.png" width="160" height="725" alt=""><a/></div>'''
When i take the obvios step of adding the missing image tag, the next error is,  "a" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</a>"

Comment: Every tag you open must be closed as well. So when you write `<a>` to mark the start you have to write `</a>` to mark the end. The parser you are using is telling you, that you have not done that for that specific tag, but instead wrote something else. Recheck the code you have that the start- and end-tags match. You might want to use special "empty tags" for tags which do not have a body per se, like the `<img />` tag.

Comment: Ok so now i got that all fixed and no errors, but when i upload it, the image is visible but not hyperlinked.

Comment: "  <div id='RightFloatAds' style='right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;'>
  <a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'><img alt='' height='725' src='http://www.ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/></a> </div>"

Answer (score 0):

Your html has so many issues...

First of all, attributes of HTML elements must be after element's name and before `>`:
`<div id="blah" otherattribute="value">`

Second, there is no `;` allowed in attribute ID.

Third, you are missing `</a>` and instead of closing `</div>` you have invalid `</div>`

And finally try avoid use inline styles, use CSS instead if all possible of course.

```html
<div id="RightFloatAds" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1"><img src="banner1news.png" width="160" height="725" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the </a> as well as changing that </div> were both also foolhardy attempts at fixing this. I should have been more descriptive in my question of what i have tried.

Comment: How about you post the original code and also give information what exactly gives you the error. Is this the only line you trying to post?

Comment: '''<div id="RightFloatAds" style="right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&id=1"><img src="banner1news.png" width="160" height="725" alt=""><a/></div>'''  original code

Comment: Yes it is the only line i am trying to post. Everything else works. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4655; columnNumber: 223; The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: I've update the answer, perhaps the error comes from `&` in the href, it should be escaped:  `&amp;`

Comment: Thanks, but it still isn't working. Its giving this error to your solution. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4656; columnNumber: 138; The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>".

Comment: "Unlike paragraph, header, or list tags, the image tag doesn't require a closing tag." I don't know what that error is about. In any case, make it happy by adding `</img>` before `</a>` or add `/` before `>`

Comment: I fixed that error,  and i was able to get it accepted without any errors.  However, the banner shows up but without it's link.  """"  <div id='RightFloatAds' style='right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;'>
  <a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'><img alt='' height='725' src='http://www.ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/></a> </div>""""

Comment: It looks fine, must be your blog messing with you...try use devtools to make sure the link actually is missing. p.s.  use `` when posting inline code here

Comment: I used devtools as you suggested and the link is there. It's not missing.  Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: If the link is there, there is nothing to fix...

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question by changing the format of the img src.  After making these changes, there is no longer an error.

''''
 ''''

Comment: '''' <div id='RightFloatAds' style='right: 0px; position: fixed; text-align: center; top: 65px; background-color:black;color:black;border:5px solid black;'>
  <a href='http://www.ramycapital.ca/?p=subscribe&amp;id=1' target='_blank'><img alt='' height='725' src='http://www.ramycapital.ca/images/banner1news.png' width='160'/></a> </div>''''

Answer (score -1):

remove the semi-colon from your id (;)

Comment: Adding that semi-colon was one of my attempted fixes.